# Flags com contagens de sinalizações para revisão, moderação e outros

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, flags

Costumava ver dois meios alaranjados e/ou acastanhados à direita das minhas medalhas, agora vejo um azul à esquerda do meu *avatar*!

[image: Captura de Tela]

São testes ao sistema? Existem efectivamente 3 destes pequenos contadores com sinalizações? Qual o objectivo de cada?

<sup>Todas estas mudanças causam um pouco de confusão pelo que seria bom uma explicação, preferencialmente em Português.</sup>

Comment: Quer que eu responda ou está esperando algo oficial?

Comment: @bfavaretto Nada oficial, demora muito, força ai :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Azul

Número de sinalizadores pendentes na fila de quem tem o privilégio "acesso às ferramentas de moderação". Antes era laranja e mais à direita, como você disse.

#### Marrom/Castanho

Número de edições sugeridas pendentes na fila de análise/revisão correspondente. Continua com a mesma cor que tinha antes, e na mesma posição.

---

Uns dois dias atrás parece que eles testaram várias cores, e acabaram escolhendo essas para todos os sites da rede (antes as cores podiam variar por site). Discussão relacionada no metão: [More consistent and contrasted color scheme for the top bar indicators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223085/more-consistent-and-contrasted-color-scheme-for-the-top-bar-indicators)